# functions and rotating char

Tags: c++, function, rotation

I am in need of your help! I'm trying to make this program work to read in four characters and then prints them out in a rotated pattern. When done rotating  the four characters, it will read another four characters and rotate them. It repeats this process of reading and rotating until end-of-file.

When I run the program, it does not print 4 times. it prints one time and does not rotate anything.

Here's my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int NUM_STEPS = 4;   // number of rotation steps to perform

void DisplayRotationPattern(char c1, char c2, char c3, char c4);
void DisplayFourChars(char c1, char c2, char c3, char c4);


//     This function "rotates" four characters c1, c2, c3, and c4.
//     That is, it puts c2 in c1, c3 in c2, c4 in c3, and c1 in c4.
void RotateFourChars(char c1, char c2, char c3, char c4);


int main()
{
   char ch1, ch2, ch3, ch4;   

   cout << "Enter four characters: ";
   cin >> ch1 >> ch2 >> ch3 >> ch4;

   while( cin )
   {
      cout << "The Rotation patterns are:" << endl;

      DisplayFourChars(ch1, ch2, ch3, ch4);



      cout << "Enter four characters: ";
      cin >> ch1 >> ch2 >> ch3 >> ch4;
   }

   return 0;
}


//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
// This function displays the four characters passed to it
// in a rotated pattern.
// params: (in, in, in, in)
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
void DisplayRotationPattern(char c1, char c2, char c3, char c4)
{
   int count = 1;
   while (count <= NUM_STEPS)
   {

      DisplayFourChars( c1, c2, c3, c4);
      cout << endl;


      RotateFourChars( c1,  c2,  c3, c4 );
      count ++;
   }

}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------       
// This function "rotates" four characters c1, c2, c3, and c4.
// That is, it puts c2 in c1, c3 in c2, c4 in c3, and c1 in c4.
// params: (inout, inout, inout, inout)
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
void RotateFourChars(char c1, char c2, char c3, char c4)
{  

      char temp;

       temp = c1;
       c1 = c2;
       c2 = c3;
       c3 = c4;
       c4 = temp;


}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
// This function has four input parameters, each of them is a character.
// The function displays the four characters at the beginning of a line.
// params: (in, in, in, in)
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

void DisplayFourChars(char c1, char c2, char c3, char c4)

{

    cout << c1 << c2 << c3 << c4 << endl;

}
```

Comment: Use references for the RotateFourChars method (char& c1,...). C++ works Call-By-Value.

Comment: You also have to call `DisplayRotationPattern()` instead of just `DisplayFourChars()`.

Comment: You are calling 'DisplayFourChars' function. Where are you rotating?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're passing by value in the `RoateFourCharacters` function.

Change to pass-by-reference:

```
 void RotateFourChars(char& c1, char& c2, char& c3, char& c4)
 {  
     char temp;

     temp = c1;
     c1 = c2;
     c2 = c3;
     c3 = c4;
     c4 = temp;
 }
```

Or, you could use pointers:

```
 void RotateFourChars(char* c1, char* c2, char* c3, char* c4)
 {  
     char temp;

     temp = *c1;
     *c1 = *c2;
     *c2 = *c3;
     *c3 = *c4;
     *c4 = temp;
 }

 // And when calling, make sure to pass the address of the chars
 RotateFourChars(&c1, &c2, &c3, &c4);
```

Comment: Thanks, I did change it to pass-by-reference, and now the program does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Change your `RotateFourChars` function as follow

In declaration part,

```
void RotateFourChars(char& c1, char& c2, char& c3, char& c4)
```

Also in definition part,

```
void RotateFourChars(char& c1, char& c2, char& c3, char& c4){
}
```

One more thing is that you do not call the `RotateFourChars` function in your `main()`

```
while( cin )
{
    cout << "The Rotation patterns are:" << endl;
    RotateFourChars(ch1, ch2, ch3, ch4);          // <-- call RotateFourChars here
    //DisplayRotationPattern(ch1, ch2, ch3, ch4); // <-- call DisplayRotationpattern
    DisplayFourChars(ch1, ch2, ch3, ch4);         // <-- instead of calling this
```

Comment: Thanks! I got most of it to work! What it's showing is that it prints 5 lines (rotations) instead of 4. I'm trying to figure this out